# Typescript map array of keys to array of properties

Tags: typescript

I would like to do something like this:

```
type A = { a: string; b: number; c: boolean };
type B = ["b", "a"];

type C = MapProps<A, B> ?? // [number, string]
```

The closest I can get is:

```
type C = {[key in B[number]]: A[key]}
```

But that results in an object, whereas I would like to discard the keys and just keep the values as tuple, with the same order as `B`. I.e., is there something `Object.values()` on type level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We will need to use recursive conditional types here. The logic is as follows:

In each iteration, we get the first element(`K`) from the `B` and store `A[K]` in some result(`R`) array. We continue this until `B` is empty and then we return `R`.

Implementation:

```
type MapProps<
  T,
  Keys extends PropertyKey[],
  Result extends unknown[] = []
> = Keys extends [
  infer First extends keyof T,
  ...infer Rest extends PropertyKey[]
]
  ? MapProps<T, Rest, [...Result, T[First]]>
  : Result;
```

`PropertyKey` is a built-in type for any key: `string | number | symbol`.

To get the first and the rest of the elements from the array type we used the [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) keyword.

Testing:

```
type A = { a: string; b: number; c: boolean };
type B = ["b", "a"];

type C = MapProps<A, B>; // [number, string]
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmACgJwPZgM4B4CwAoKKAFQBp9CBpCEDKCAD2AgDsATWldCZUKkAbQC6ZAlABKEDAFcANsDqMW7KFOYBrZqgDuzIVAC8UIfgB8BqH1oMmbWv3JQAlswBm3KADFHyDPOtLaNWpUF2IRQgA6KOc3ZHFJP0VbKE5IHhA+YzxBBwB+WARU7FJ43xIjKIiJaTlyon4vH2BBQRMHAC5S2WAAbnx8UEgoAEFzAG8oOE7fZGcAcx6oACNO5ikAWyXuRYBjTqXUVBkIOGYoAF8+vEHoACFzfgAiJcfyx7hHwSuB8GgAYXM8CQaEwWGG5VuJkWAHpoUY1ptuOUZvMcnggA)

Comment: Very beautiful solution!

Comment: `... infer Rest` looks like cursed syntax but nice solution

Comment: Great, thanks! I went with `(keyof T)[]` instead of `PropertyKey[]` but that shouldn't really matter, right?